# Show that two sigma-algebras are the same

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ be an uncountable space. Denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the
sigma-algebra on $X$ that consists of all subsets $A$ of $X$ for which either $A$
or $A^c$ is countable. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the smallest sigma-algebra on $X$ which
contains all sets $\{x\}$, for all $x \in X$. Show that $\mathcal{A} =\mathcal{F}$.

Proof.

Let $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\{x\}) = \{\{x\} : x \in X\}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(A) = \{A \subset X: \# A < \infty$ or $\# A^c < \infty\}$. Then to show that $\mathcal{A} =\mathcal{F}$ it is necessary to show that $\sigma(\{x\})\subset \sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma(\{x\})$.
Since $\{x\}$ is the smallest subset of $X$ and $A \subset X $ it follows that $\{x\} \subset A$ and hence $\sigma(\{x\})\subset \sigma(A)$.

Now I need to show that $A \subset \{x\}$, but $A$ can have more than one element.
Can someone please give a hint?

Comment: Replace "$\mathcal F=\sigma(\{x\})$" (which is formally  incorrect) by "$\mathcal F=\sigma(\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$" and remove "$=\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$" (which is drastically false: that set is not a $\sigma$-algebra). Then, replace "$<\infty$" by $=\sharp\mathbb N$. Remove "$\sigma(A)$" (which has no more meaning than the previous "$\sigma(\{x\})$").

Comment: $\{x\}$ (which is far from unique) is not "the smallest subset of $X$": the smallest is $\varnothing$. Then you say $\{x\}\subset A$ but which $x$ and which $A$? Anyway, that does not prove what follows your "hence" (even rewritten correctly). Finally, for the reverse inclusion *of the $\sigma$-algebras, not of their elements*, you do not "need to show that $A\subset\{x\}$" (again, that means nothing: which $x$ and which $A$?).

Comment: Just a tiny correction of my first comment: I should have written $\le\sharp\mathbb N$ instead of $=\sharp\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

- $\mathcal A\subset\cal F$: Let $A\in\cal A$.
  * If $A$ is countable then it is a countable union of singletons hence $A\in\mathcal F$ (because all singletons $\{x\}\subset X$ belong to $\cal F$ and $\cal F$ is closed under countable unions).
  * If $A^c$ is countable then, by the previous sentence, $A^c\in\cal F$, hence $A=(A^c)^c\in\cal F$ (because $\cal F$ is closed under complementation).
- $\mathcal F\subset\cal A$: any singleton $\{x\}\subset X$ is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) hence belongs to $\cal A$. Hence (by definition) the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal F$ *generated by* these singletons is contained in the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal A$.